# binomial theorem combinatorics intuition

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, intuition, binomial-theorem

I have a doubt regarding the explanation behind the combinatorial proof of the binomial theorem:

Consider $(x+y)^{4}$. For instance, Why is the coefficient of $x^{2}y^{2}$ the number of ways in which I can select 2 $x$s and 2 $y$s from the four different factors that result from expanding $(x+y)^{4}$?

Comment: Try expanding $(x_1+y_1)(x_2+y_2)(x_3+y_3)(x_4+y_4)$  and look at the six terms of the form $x_ix_jy_my_n$ for an intuitive idea

Answer (score 1):

$(x+ y)^2= (x+ y)(x+ y)= x(x+ y)+ y(x+ y)= x^2+ **xy**+ **yx**+ y^2= x^2+ **2**xy+ y^2$.
The "2" is from adding "xy" and "yx".

$(x+ y)^3= (x+ y)(x^2+ 2x+ y^2)= x(x^2+ 2xy+ y^2)+ y(x^2+ 2xy+ y^2)= x^3+ **2x^2y**+ **xy^2**+ **x^2y**+ **2xy^2**+ y^3= x^3+ **3**x^2y+ **3**xy^2+ y^3$
The first "3" is from adding "$2x^2y" and "$x^2y$" and 
the second is from adding "$xy^2$" and "$2xy^2$".

$(x+ y)^4= (x+ y)(x^3+ 3x^2y+ 3xy^2+ y^3)= x(x^3+ 3x^2y+ 3xy^2+ y^3)+ y(x^3+ 3x^2y+ 3xy^2+ y^3)= x^4+ **3x^3y**+ **3x^2y^2**+ **xy^3**+ **x^3y**+ **3x^2y^2**+ **3xy^3**+ y^4= x^4+ **4**x^3y+ **6**x^2y^2+ **4**x^3y+ y^4$
The first "4" is from adding "$3x^3y$" and "$x^3y$" and the second is from adding "$xy^3$" and "$3xy^3$".  The "6" is from adding "$3x^2y^2$" and "$3x^2y^2$".